# HP Laser printing pattern on all pages HP LaserJet CP2025

Tags: printing, printer, hp-laserjet

I have a 3 week old HP LaserJet CP2025 that was working fine.  A few days ago I notice a light pattern is printing on ALL pages printed.  The pattern is grey, on the left side of the page about half way or somewhat past.   It is about 2 inches high by 1-1.5 inches wide - no difference in the pattern between pages, whether color or not.

It resembles what might happen with a bad fuser, or possibly some internal rollers/wheels are dirty.

We cleaned the rollers at the top and pulled the black cartridge and see nothing abnormal.

We ran the cleaning page function at least 8 times, no difference.

What do you think/what should we try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a small bit of paper stuck in the rollers!  It was not easy to spot at first.

Answer (score 0):

I know toner is expensive, but as it has a long shelf life try replacing the toners one at a time. In my office when we see any pattern it nearly always corresponds to a leaking or dirty toner cartridge.